Is there a specific term in English used to refer to two antonyms that are also synonyms of each other?
For example:
"Up" and "down" are definitely antonyms, but they can be used as synonyms like in these sentences

Are you up for a game night?


Are you down for a game night?

Or the words "sick" and "well":

You're sick at this game!


You play this game well!

I have yet to come across any word that describes such a relationship, so I've started calling them "Synchronyms" until I can find their official name, if there is one.
An autoantonym is a single word that is the antonym of itself. What I'm asking about refers to two different words that are antonyms of each other, yet, in certain contexts, they're deemed synonyms of each other.
For example: "Up" is not an autoantonym nor is "down," but they are both antonyms and synonyms of each other depending on context.
As in "up" means the opposite of "down," BUT "up" also means the same thing as "down."
For example: "look up!" is the opposite of "look down!"
Yet, "I'm down to play that game!" and "I'm up to play that game!" mean the same thing. Note: Being "down" to do something is not an autoantonym of any other definition of "down." Just as being "up" to do something is not an autoautonym of any other definition of "up."
Also, it doesn't matter how recent a word gained a new meaning (for example: "sick" gaining the meaning of "super cool" as a slang term from the 90s). It's still a synonym and antonym of "well" depending on context despite "sick" being an autoantonym in this case (You are sick for the many crimes you've committed/you are sick at skateboarding!), "well" is not an autoantonym, thus meaning a synchronym does not require autoantonyms on either side (example: up/down) to be one. While autoantonyms can definitely be apart of a synchronym pair, they aren't necessarily going to be.
If I find more examples of synchronyms (And I know there are many), I'll definitely add them to my question.
Further examples:
"Heal" and "purge."
Antonym:

"To heal someone." "To purge someone."

Synonym:

"To heal someone from evil." "To purge evil from someone."


These words are individually contronyms (auto-antonyms). It seems like there is no specific term for their contronymic relationship. Perhaps, contronym(ic) pair or contronymic antonyms could work. Or I could coin "antosynonyms".

They are only synonyms in very informal usage.  Using sick to mean good or well is a very recent coinage.

This must involve auto-antonymy, where a word has two meanings which are antonyms (eg 'cleave'; 'dust'; 'plug'. Here, 'sick' carries the sense 'skilled; ace' in contrast to 'poor, poorly'. I'd say close enough for a duplicate close-vote.

This question is similar to: Can anyone provide me with a list of English words that are their own antonyms? and Is the term antagonym widely used to describe a word that is its own antonym?. If you believe it’s ...

different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on those questions are not helpful for your problem.

Your examples are clever. But they only work by implying the same result, not because of the same word meaning. Up there is energized, down means in agreement. Sick is good only in the sarcastic sense. Evil is good that way. Nuts and crazy are fun that way. Phat is cool that way.
